Get page views from google analytic 4 in React
I have a react nodejs project and have some products in my site. I setup Google Analytic 4 with package 'react-ga4', Now i simply want to get a number of views for every product. I searched and came across thousands of answers that are not for ga4.
Tried to write custom hook based on Method: properties.runReport to get views.
at the end of document it said:

Authorization scopes Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics

(Its the first time i use googleapis and what is this mean???)
my custom hook : usePageViews.jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const PROPERTY_ID = '443322111';
// const YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN = '???????';
// const PROPERTY_ID = 'properties/443322111';//have tried

const usePageViews = (productId) => {
  const [viewCount, setViewCount] = useState(0);

  const body = {
    dimensions: [{ name: 'pagePath' }],
    metrics: [{ name: 'totalUsers' }],
    dimensionFilter: {
      filter: {
        fieldName: 'pagePath',
        stringFilter: {
          matchType: 'CONTAINS',
          value: `https://my-website.com/product/${productId}`,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      Content_Type: 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      // Authorization: `Bearer ${YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      // Authorization: `Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`, // have tried
    },
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPageViews = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${PROPERTY_ID}:runReport`,
          // `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport`,
          body,
          config
        );

        const dataRows = response.data.reports[0].data.rows;
        const pageViews =
          dataRows.length > 0 ? parseInt(dataRows[0].metrics[0].values[0]) : 0;

        setViewCount(pageViews);
      } catch (error) {}
    };

    fetchPageViews();
  }, [productId]);

  return viewCount;
};

export default usePageViews;


I did'nt know how can i obtain YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN.Then found :
const PROPERTY_ID = '443322111';
const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000'; 
const CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID'; 
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];
const responseType = 'token';

// Function to initiate OAuth 2.0 flow
const initiateOAuthFlow = () => {
  const queryParams = {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    response_type: responseType,
    scope: SCOPES.join(' '),
  };
  const queryString = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
  const authUrl = `${AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT}?${queryString}`;
  window.location.href = authUrl;
};

// To initiate authentication
initiateOAuthFlow();


// After successful authentication, handle the token in the redirect URI
const handleTokenInRedirectURI = () => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.substring(1));
  const accessToken = params.get('access_token');
  // Use the access token in your API requests
  return accessToken;
};

// Call this function to handle the token in the redirect URI
const YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN = handleTokenInRedirectURI();


At the end, i defined project in google credentials and obtain CLIENT_ID and put REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000' for test in local.
Every time i got an error. Can anyone explain what exaclty i should do. Should i got YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN in my frontend every time for ga4 or what? I was stuck for hours!
